# Add a string before each number in a series

Tags: python, concatenation

I want to convert 
the series

```
tt = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]
```

into

```
output = ['Cal 2015', 'Cal 2016', ...]
```

I know that in R I can simply write as:

```
paste('Cal',2015:2024,sep = " ")
```

However in Python when I tried

```
'Cal' + str(tt)
```

The result is

```
'Cal[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]'
```

Does anyone know how to do the string concatenation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

If you must use a for-loop, you can do this:

```
>>> tt = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]
>>> lst = []
>>> for t in tt:
...     lst.append("Cal {}".format(t))
...
>>> lst
['Cal 2015', 'Cal 2016', 'Cal 2017', 'Cal 2018', 'Cal 2019', 'Cal 2020', 'Cal 2021', 'Cal 2022', 'Cal 2023', 'Cal 2024']
>>>
```

---

---

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> tt = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]
>>> ["Cal {}".format(t) for t in tt]
['Cal 2015', 'Cal 2016', 'Cal 2017', 'Cal 2018', 'Cal 2019', 'Cal 2020', 'Cal 2021', 'Cal 2022', 'Cal 2023', 'Cal 2024']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, here requires a for loop - would it be slower?

Comment: @Twinkle - Yes, the for-loop will be slower than the list comprehension.  However, if you must use one, I included a demonstration in my answer.  Also, `str.format` is a string method that allows you to format strings.  In this case, `"Cal {}".format(t)` will take `t` and insert it where the `{}` is.  It is equivalent to doing `"Cal "+str(t)`.

Comment: @iCodez I think you can speed it up a little bit, but storing `"Cal {}".format`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to iCodez's solution.

```
>>>l=["Cal"+str(i) for i in tt]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of using for loop without creating a new list:

```
tt = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]
for i,x in enumerate(tt):
    tt[i] = 'Cal ' + str(x)
```